# Android: Get Cache File Information using Package Name

Tags: android

Is there a possibility to get the cache file information of the application that is installed in my mobile phone using the package name? if not, what is the other possible way to get the cache file information of the application? because I want to get the cache file size, cache file location etc. of the particular application in my mobile phone Programmatically

Answer (score 0):

this could be what you are looking for [getCacheDir()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getCacheDir%28%29)